# Create a file according to the value in databsse

Tags: php, mysql, rename, filenames

I know how to create a php file from php code. But I want to rename the file according to the value taken from the database. For example, if the value is Blue, i want the file name to be blue.php. I am not sure how to do it.

```php
$filename = "blue.php"; //file i want to rename
$ourFileName = $filename;
$ourFileHandle = fopen($ourFileName, 'w');
$written = "
    <html>
    <body>
    <?php
    echo \"I like the color {$row['color']}!!!!\"; //value that i want the file name to be based on
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

fwrite($ourFileHandle, $written);
fclose($ourFileHandle);
```

Comment: take a look at the rename function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Comment: so the above works? where is the query to the db to get "Blue" ?

Answer (score 1):

I gonna use for this example [PDO connection](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Let say you hava table in database, something like this.

table name: **settings**

```
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | name    | property            |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | color   | red                 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
```

**Create file**

When you wanna to create a new file, with new name. You just need to edit `row[id=1]` in database.

First we need to edit `row[id=1]` to make a new file name.

```php
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';

$NewColor = 'green';

$UpdateDataBase = $conn->prepare("UPDATE settings SET property = ? WHERE id = 1");
$UpdateDataBase->execute([$NewColor]);
```

> Whit that we changed `property` for row with `ID = 1` in our database. From `red` to `green`.

Now we need to use [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fclose()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)

We now going to take `green` from our database, in order to create new file.

```php
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';

// We gonna take a row from database where id = 1. Because that ID has our information.
$NewFileName  =  $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1")
$NewFileName->execute();

// Now we will open foreach loop.
foreach($NewFileName->fetchAll() as $row){
   $NewFile = 'path/to/the/file/'.$row['property'].'.php';

  // now we gonna use fopen()
  fopen($NewFile, 'w');
  fclose($NewFile);
}
```

**Rename File**

Now we gonna use [rename()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

```php
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';

$oldfile = 'path/to/the/file/red.php';

$RenameFile= $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM settings WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1");
$RenameFile->execute();
foreach ($RenameFile->fetchAll as $row){
  $newfile = 'path/to/the/file/'.$row['property'].'.php';

  // Now we gonna use rename()
  rename($oldfile, $newfile);
}
```

But before u gonna use this, check this out [**Hacking using “rename()” of PHP**](https://safecode.dev/en/2019/04/16/hacking-using-rename-of-php/)

Comment: You have to make sure the values from the DB is safe to use in a file name / file path.

Comment: I know, thats way I put that link over there. He must do something to prevent xss or something different

Comment: Can i create new file? I dont want to rename a file, i want to create a new file

Comment: This is then another question.

Comment: I updated answer. Take a look maybe this gonna help you.